# Sharing objects between Java classes without going via a method

Tags: java

I'm looking at a way to add some tracing diagnostics to some legacy Java code.  By legacy in this sense I mean I cannot change any of the methods.  If we consider the following objects:

```
public class ClassIOwnAndCanChange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // store my object here that I want to make
        // available in LegacyClassA and B
        myMethod("foo", 100);
    }    

}

public class LegacyClassA {

    // method I cannot change
    public void myMethod(String name, int timer) {

        //want to get my 'injected' object here so that I can, 
        //for instance, time this method
        methodCallThatTakesSomeTime("some param");

    }  

}

public class LegacyClassB {

    // method I cannot change
    public void methodCallThatTakesSomeTime(String name) {
        // want to get my 'injected' object here for
        // diagnostic reasons

    }

}
```

I own A and I would like to make an object available in B and C.  What is the right way to do this in Java without changing the method that A calls on B and the method that B calls on C?

Comment: You will have to improve your question to get answers. Maybe provide example using some names for instance `methodOfA`, `methodOfB` etc. Seems to me from the title a static member may do the job, but it is possible I misunderstand you

Comment: sort of global reference...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play all sorts of games with AOP ([Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)) and/or other forms of bytecode manipulation.

Whether or not you *should* varies wildly.

It depends on your *precise* needs, and how you need to use the "injected" object. I'd consider AOP first since tools like [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/) are mature. AOP and a `ThreadLocal` might be all you need.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and also the ThreadLocal suggestion.  I'll investigate those two in detail